# Android: Create fragment toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar, fragment

I want to make a persistent toolbar (with icons) which launches fragment activities into another fragment. I followed [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html#fragments_tutorial), but I can't figure out how to turn the listview into a horizontal toolbar under the DetailFragment display.

I've tried to add buttons to the fragment, but there is no equivalent for setContentView for fragments. Also, Android doesn't seem to have any horizontal Listviews.

I looked at ActionBar as well, but that doesn't seem to be exactly what I want.

In general, how does one go about creating a persistent toolbar that launches activities in an Android app?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Your question is a little difficult to understand. Are you looking for an `ActionBar` substitute? What's a `toolbar`? Use `onCreateView` in `Fragments`

Comment: "I want to make a persistent toolbar (with image icons) that launches fragment activities into another fragment." -- this is not possible. You cannot put fragments into another fragment, and you cannot put activities into a fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to responders!
I realized that a tabhost that implements fragments solves my problem.

Here's a really good tutorial that I found. I hope it helps someone else. 
http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/android-tabs-the-fragment-way/

Answer (score 0):

ActionBar really does seem to be the right option here

**Have a menu XML which sets Icons**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
   <item android:id="@+id/action_frag1" android:title="@string/action_frag1"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
        android:orderInCategory="450" app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item android:id="@+id/action_frag2" android:title="@string/action_frag2"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_revert"
        android:orderInCategory="400" app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    ...
</menu>
```

**Use it from Activity and respond to Presses**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case android.R.id.action_frag1:
            //Here we change the fragment
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction tr = fm.beginTransaction();
            tr.replace(R.id.container, Fragment1.newInstance());
            tr.commit();
            break;
        case R.id.action_frag2:
            ... // same thing, but stay DRY
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```